# Oracle SQL content based selection

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table:

```
 AGENT  CLIE
 -----------
 A         1
 B         1
 A         2
 B         2
 C         1
```

The result I want is:

```
 AGENT  CLIE
 -----------
 A         2
 B         2
 C         1
```

So I want to only show the highest rank clients if existent, otherwise show the entry.

For A and B there are higher level clients but for c there is none.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select agent, max(clie)
from your_table
group by agent
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "2" is a better rank than "1" here, you can use the MAX function:

```
SELECT
    AGENT, max(CLIE) 
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    AGENT

(optional) ORDER BY AGENT
```

Comment: Arigato gozaimas!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, if you want only `agent` and max `clie` in the output, then use simple aggregation:

```
Select agent, max(clie)
From your_table
Group by agent
```

If you have other columns and you want those too in the output corresponding to the row with max `clie`, use window function `row_number` (or `rank` if you want all row with max clie for each `agent`):

```
Select *
From (
  Select t.*,
    Row_number() over (
       Partition by agent
       Order by clie desc nulls last
    ) as rn
  From your_table t
  ) t
Where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup mon amie